# Get key and value of a hash passed to a module from the site.pp class when declaring the class

Tags: puppet

I have classes that I would like them to receive hashes as declaration arguments for the node they are in but  need to get the key and the value of the hash separately and then manipulate them to do what I want. Let me elaborate on this

```
     node 'node' {
           hash => {
                    "hash key "  => "value" or
                    "hash key" => ["value1","value2"]
                }
          }
```

Then in the target class I can have the following

```
           resource { "hash key":
                        attribute => "value" or
                       attrubute => ["value1","value2"]
         }
```

Is it possible If so guidance is welcome and if not any workarounds are welcome ...This would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're building your hash awkwardly, but in spirit, this is what the [create_resources function](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/function.html#createresources) is all about.

```
$hash = {
  'title1' => {
    'attr1' => 'value1',
    'attr2' => 'value2',
    ...
  },
  'title2' => { ... },
  ...
}

create_resources('my::custom::type', $hash)
```

As the name implies, the function creates a resource of the given type for each hash key, defining its attributes from the inner hashes.

Comment: Thanks Felix will be back with results after trying